# Заменить цикл while на рекурсию

Tags: циклы, pascal, рекурсия, pascalabc.net

Есть задание: написать рекурсивную функцию, вычисляющую НОД (наибольший общий делитель) используя модифицированный алгоритм Евклида (методом вычитания). Проблема в том, что я с циклом могу выполнить это задание, а с рекурсией - не получается, начинается путаница. Один из вариантов моей функции (правильно работающей) с while:

```pascal
function GCD(A, B: integer): integer;
begin
  while A<>B do
  if A>B then A:=A-B 
  else B:=B-A;
  GCD:=A;
end;
```

И вот попытка с рекурсией (тут каша полная):

```
function GCD(A, B: integer): integer;
begin
  if (A - B) = 0 then exit;
  A:= A - B;
  writeln(A); // это чтобы увидеть как меняется значение А
  GCD:=A;
  if A > B then GCD(A,B)
  else GCD(B,A);
end;
```

Которая в результате, например, с числами 124 и 28 выдает в конце напечатанного списка 4, но значение функции все равно остается 96, и я примерно понимаю, почему это, но не понимаю, как это исправить, потому что не понимаю саму рекурсию. Очень нужна помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  GCD := A;
  if (A - B) = 0 then exit;
  A := A - B;
  if A > B then GCD := GCD(A, B)
  else GCD := GCD(B, A);
```